# How can I use binary output in switch cases?

Tags: powershell, binary, registry

```
 $var1 = [byte]0xDB,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x02,0x04,0xF4,0x00,0x00,0x00
 $var2 = [byte]0xDB,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x03,0xF1,0x00,0x00,0x00

 $value = Get-ItemProperty -Path $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 switch ($value)
       $var1 {act1}
       $var2 {act2}
```

This command
 `Get-ItemProperty -Path $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` outputs:

> 219 1 0 0 16 0 0 0 1 1 0 4 242 0 0 0

But apparently **switch**  only works if the output in such form:

> [byte]0xDB,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x03,0xF1,0x00,0x00,0x00

So I need somehow convert one of those variables for the switch to work or maybe use different commands

Comment: Why don't you convert those byte arrays to hex strings and use those hex strings instead

Comment: On a side note, to correctly create a byte array: `[byte[]] (0xDB,0x01,…)`. In your examples, only the first element of the array will be of type byte.

Comment: Data is 128 bits so I would make a string using Following : [string]::Join('', ($var1 | foreach { $_.ToString("X2")}))

Comment: `switch ("$value")` `"$var1" {act1}` `"$var2" {act2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, when you pass a collection to a `switch` each element is evaluated separately. For example:

```
switch (1,2,6) { 
    1 {"one"} 
    6 { "six"} 
    default { "default" } }
```

outputs:

```
one
default
six
```

Second, the matches typically should be numbers, strings or some expression that returns a boolean, so your vars are being converted to strings. From [about_switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.3):

> Any unquoted value that is not recognized as a number is treated as a
> string. To avoid confusion or unintended string conversion, you should
> always quote string values. Enclose any expressions in parentheses (),
> creating subexpressions, to ensure that the expression is evaluated
> correctly.

So, if you just convert your input to a string, it should work:

```
switch ("$value")
{
   "$var1" {act1}
   "$var2" {act2}
}
```